# How to redirect one route to my PHP file, all others to my React app

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have built a React app with a PHP proxy inside. According to my `.htaccess`, all routes will redirect to `index.html`. However, I want that if an app calls `example.com/proxy`, the response to come from my `proxy.php` file inside the `proxy` folder and not to return an HTML file.

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

If I access `/proxy`, I want to have the data from `example.com/proxy/proxy.php`. Also, `example.com/proxy` will have parameters and content after (eg. `example.com/proxy/compare?apiKey=saksjdskadj&sort=blablabla`)

Comment: How should `/compare?apiKey=saksjdskadj&sort=blablabla` be passed to proxy.php? Do you want the query string passed through as-is, and parse the requested URI to extract "compare"? Or pass this as part of the query string as well?

Comment: Ok, so basically when I did it, I would access ``localhost/proxy/compare?apiKey=saksjdskadj&sort=blablabla`, use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to extract `/compare?apiKey=saksjdskadj&sort=blablabla` and work with that in my PHP script.

So yeah, just pass it through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probaby is what you are looking for:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/proxy/proxy\.php$
RequestRule ^/proxy/(.+)$ /proxy/proxy.php?action=$1 [QSA,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [QSA,END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).